# issue with here map geocode

Tags: dictionary, here-api, geocode

I have problem with here map API.

i want to implement first default position for map. When user search for some location it should move to the location. Simple right. But i am bit lost.

```js
//i define parameter.
var geocodingParams = { searchText: 'location address' };

// Get an instance of the geocoding service:
var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();

// Call the geocode method with the geocoding parameters,
// the callback and an error callback function (called if a
// communication error occurs):
geocoder.geocode(geocodingParams, onResult, onError);

// results when success
function onResult(result) {
        var locations = result.response.view[0].result;
        alert(JSON.stringify(locations));
}

// on Error
function onError(e) {
        alert(e);
}
```

it is giving error only. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is throwing an error is because it cannot find the address 'location address'.

I think you should change the address to something like : '425 W Randolph Chicago' and then try again.

If it still does not work, try changing  `result.response.view[0].result;` to `result.Response.View[0].Result;`
Also, what you could do is check if you are receiving any response:

```
if(result.Response.View) 
            {
            var locations = result.Response.View[0].Result;
            alert(JSON.stringify(locations));
            }
else
alert("Blank response");`
```